# Large Leaflet Polymaps need online home

Tags: r, leaflet

I have a series of different maps made with leaflet and R.  I need to be able to display these maps somewhere that is accessible online.

The file sizes are too large for Rpubs, some coming in at over 120 MB.

I have tried Rpubs, too large
I have tried rediculous WIX websites and similar but they don't have the capabilities to show that.
I have tried emailing them, that doesn't work.

I need maps, online that can be accessed.  Someone just please throw ideas at me, I have been fighting with this for 24 hours now trying to get my finalized maps to the person that needs them!

Comment: Save locally and then wetransfer to clients? They can host them on a privatye/local server when needed..

Comment: I guess I am unsure if the maps even work outside of my environment currently.  To be honest I don't quite understand how the html knitting occurs with leaflet to html.

Comment: try the `htmlwidget`-package